# Sources for Rambam

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rambam

Is there a commentary on Mishneh Torah that connects the Rambam's words to his source in the gemara? I'm looking for something similar to the Be'er Hagola to the Shulhan Arukh, or an inverse En Mishpat Ner Misvah.

Comment: One of the better commentators is the Avodat HaMelch which is only extant on Sefer Mada. There is also Rav Kafih's awesomely comprehensive commentary to the MT (although this does not focus exclusively on sourcing). One important feature of his commentary, is that it differentiates between the Talmud, and Rashi and Tosafot. While this seems obvious, many commentators are so used to reading the Geamara like Rashi and Tosafot, that they fail to realize that the source for Rambam may be a differing reading of the same Gemara.

Answer (score 5):

1. The Rashash wrote a comment called מקורי הרמב"ם [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/7222)
2. In the Rambam Fraenckel edition you can find all mekorot [here](http://www.fridmanbooks.co.il/ProductInfo.asp?ProdId=88&catId=101#.V0rJ77FBTcs).
3. In the Rambam Hashalem moreh shiur of Chabad there is a fine work with sources of each statememt in rambam [here](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/61479/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93---%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93)
4. An other very interesting book is the book of Rav Menachem Casher about the midrashe Halacha used by the Rambam [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/52260)

Comment: None of these editions use the more accurate critical texts like those of Mori Kafiẖ or Mifa'al Mishneh Torah, rather, they're based on the somewhat corrupted Vilna editions.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt thats מארי קאפח; not מורי קאפח; [common Ashkenazi variation](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/08/shadal-series-5-what-does-morenu-really.html).

Comment: @mevaqesh, Temanim still pronounce it Mori. FWIW, I don't do the more common Ashkenazi mistake of pronouncing his family name as Kapach.

Answer (score 0):

Between the מגיד משנה and מגדל עז, both printed in virtually all modern prints of the משנה תורה, at least one shows the source for most statements.